# Proof of commutativity of addition using Peano axioms

Tags: solution-verification, peano-axioms

I'm studying the proof of commutativity of addition using only Peano axioms (with the distinguished element being 0 rather than 1), the definition of addition, and x+0=0+x=x. The main idea is induction on natural numbers. I managed to prove it in one way, but the problem is I can't completely understand the other one I saw in class. Actually I doubt whether it is correct.

Here is the proof:(it uses 2 inductions)

Let A be the set A={x∈N|x+y=y+x,∀y∈N}.

We already know 0+y = y+0 ∀y∈N. Therefore 0∈A.

Suppose that x∈A.  Let B be the set B={y∈N|**ν(x)+y=y+ν(x)**}.  (v is the successor map in Peano axioms)

Note that 0∈B, since 0∈A.

Suppose that y∈B.

Then we have, using the definition of addition as well as x∈A:

ν(x) +ν(y)

=ν(ν(x) +y) [def of addition]

=ν(y+ν(x)) [assumed y∈B]

=ν(ν(y+x)) [def of addition]

=ν(ν(x+y)) [assumed x∈A]

**=ν(x+ν(y)**) [def of addition]

**=ν(ν(y) +x)**  ???

=ν(y) +ν(x)  [def of addition]

Therefore also ν(y)∈B. By Peano axiom 5(P5), we obtain that B=N. Therefore ν(x)∈A. By P5 again, A=N and addition is commutative.

I cannot understand why we can get the equation with the question marks, because I think it is something that we have not assumed.

It would be really helpful if anyone can explain why it is correct or wrong. Thank you!!

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math it's better. Thank you.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you know how induction proofs work?

Comment: The line with question marks seems to apply the hypothesis $x\in A$.

Comment: We already know 0+y = y+0 How ? The proof is by Induction, using the def of sum: $a+0=a$ and a preliminary result showing that $0+a=a$. This in turn is proved by Induction.

Comment: A second preliminary result, also this to be proved by Induction, is: $v(a)+b=v(a+b)$ (using your notation for *successor*).

Comment: Thank you Berci!!! I think you're right. Can't believe I didn't think of that! And thank you guys for recommending me to use mathjax. This is the first time I ask question here, I'll definitely learn more about that.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for commenting! I have proved these results and completed a proof of commutativity before, though it is a little bit different from the one  I posted above:)